# as.factor with levels 0, 1 instead of 1, 2

Tags: r

My variable (`poor`) is a factor with 2 levels: Poor and Non-Poor.

I need it to be 1 if it's Poor and 0 if it's Non-Poor, so i converted it to numeric (with `as.numeric`, and then changed it to factor again, with `as.factor`, but the levels now are 1 and 2 instead of 1 and 0.

How do i change it?

Comment: Try `as.factor(as.numeric(df$poor) - 1)`...?

Comment: Indexing in R is 1-based. You cannot change that it’s just not an option. Note that Sotos’ method returns a character result. The index of “0” is still 1 and the index of “1” will be 2.

Comment: @42- ahh...you are right. `as.numeric(as.factor(as.numeric(dd$v1) - 1))` still returns 1 & 2

Answer (score 4):

You want to check where `poor` is `"Poor"` and where not. So,

```
poor <- factor(c("Poor", "Non-poor", "Poor", "Non-poor"))

poor == "Poor"
```

This gives you `TRUE`/ `FALSE` for that question. If you turn that into a numeric vector, like so

```
as.numeric(poor == "Poor")
```

`TRUE`s are converted to 1s and `FALSE`s are converted to 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can index data based on it's factor level. Using @Georgery's data

```
poor <- factor(c("Poor", "Non-poor", "Poor", "Non-poor"))
c(0, 1)[poor]
#[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Or use `labels`

```
factor(c("Poor", "Non-poor", "Poor", "Non-poor"), labels = c(0, 1))
#[1] 1 0 1 0
#Levels: 0 1
```