# How to change gender factor value to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2 for my excel dataset in r

Tags: r

This is my code but everytime i view it, it still me that female is 1 and male is 2. What is wrong with my coding?

```
class(Dataset_A$gender)
Gender_numeric <- as.numeric(factor(Dataset_A$gender,levels=c("female","male"),labels=c("0","1")))
class(Gender_numeric)
View(Gender_numeric)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822013/as-factor-with-levels-0-1-instead-of-1-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `factor` to direct conversion to `numeric/integer` returns the integer storage mode values which start from 1.  Instead, we need to use `as.numeric` on the `character` converted object which is mentioned in the documentation (`?factor`)

> In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

```
Gender_numeric <- as.numeric(as.character(factor(Dataset_A$gender,
          levels=c("female",
       "male"),labels=c("0","1"))))
```

---

With a small example

```
v1 <- c("male", "female", "male", "female")
v2 <- factor(v1, levels = c("female", "male"), labels = c("0", "1"))
```

If we look at 'v2', the new `levels` are 0 and 1

```
> v2
[1] 1 0 1 0
Levels: 0 1
```

But , converting to `integer/numeric` directly

```
> as.integer(v2)
[1] 2 1 2 1
```

instead, do convert to `character` first`

```
> as.integer(as.character(v2))
[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Or may also do this using `levels` (which would be fast)

```
> as.integer(levels(v2)[v2])
[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: For this specific example, `as.numeric(factor(v1)) - 1` would also work.

Comment: that really helped! thank you